# In Magento what is the use of method hasIsValidForAddress()?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Can anyone suggest me. What is the main use of hasIsValidForAddress() function. If I disable the validation code inside canProcessRule, what impact will happen. Please suggest me, because in my custom ajax cart this validation failed to apply shopping rule for newly added item(programmatically).

```
if ($rule->hasIsValidForAddress($address) && !$address->isObjectNew()) {
        return $rule->getIsValidForAddress($address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not blindly remove the function hasIsValidForAddress(). This may affect your promotion code/ discount coupon module.

This is the function validate the quote address are valid to the discount coupon. If your website discount coupons do not vary based on the area then you can disable the function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But In cart page, when I use the same customer account in default cart the getIsValidForAddress() function return true, where in custom ajax cart it return false. Any idea? Also im confused the about the comment for hasIsValidForAddress as "Check cached validation result for specific address"